# Regex to find key value pair in a string in Python and save it in dictionary

Tags: python, json, regex, key-value, data-extraction

I want to extract key value like pairs from a string of incoming logs and store it in a dictionary in python.
The value can be in any format. It can be a string, nested lists and dictionaries. 
Example input :

```
key1:"abc pqr" prop1:abc pqr lmn response: { abc: "pqr", prop2: {lmn: 1234}}  text:["11",  222] @timestamp:May 14th 2020, 10:59:41.814
```

The python dictionary required:

```
{"key1":"abc pqr",
 "prop1:"abc pqr lmn",
 "response":'{ "abc": "pqr","prop2": '{"lmn": "1234"}'}',  
 "text":"["11",  222]", 
 "@timestamp":"May 14th 2020, 10:59:41.814"}
```

The regex pattern `re.findall(r'(\S+):(".*?"|.*?:|)', input)` is not giving required output.

Comment: Where do you expect the string to separate or split?

Comment: I want to separate it after the value ends and a new key pair begins.